# Set SELinux mode to Permissive permanently

Tags: samsung-galaxy-note-2, selinux

My Samsung Galaxy Note S2 (GT-N7102) running stock 4.3 JellyBean by default blocks all apps from Google (courtesy of the Chinese government). I followed a tutorial to gain access to gapps that relies on SELinux being set to permissive, but the mode changes on a reboot and I get a continuous stream of pop-up that says:

> Unfortunately the process com.google.gapps has stopped

What is changing the SELinux mode and how do I stop it from doing so?

Comment: Probably related: [How to make SELinux permissive on a Knox Samsung device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/64643/44325), [How can I change SELinux from Enforcing to Permissive on Samsung Galaxy Note 3?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/54577/44325)

Comment: Community bump prevention: this question was closed because the question seems to have been abandoned (OP hasn't visited the site anymore for more than 5 years and no answers have been upvoted). If anyone can evaluate the existing answers, feel free to vote accordingly and reopen the question (or mod-flag the question requesting for reopening). For anyone else having the same issue, please post a new question and refer to this question as additional context.

Answer (score 0):

When you are rooted install SELinux mode changer from playstore or here

http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2524485

Then Change SELinux to permissive grant root access and youbare done.

Comment: App has been taken off of Play Store. Also, this application only worked on Android 4.3 and earlier. Not broad enough to be considered a good answer.

Comment: Certainly not. Works fine for me. And the link takes you to xda not to google....

Answer (score 0):

If your ROM supports **init.d** or if you [wish to enable init.d support](https://www.google.com/search?q=enable+init.d+android) for this purpose, here's a way to disable SE Linux automatically everytime after each boot..

Create a new script as follows:

```
#!/system/bin/sh
setenforce 0
```

(Note: If you're using an app to emulate init.d, use `su -c setenforce 0` if just `setenforce 0` doesn't work)

Save it as `set_permissive.sh`, move it to `/system/etc/init.d/` directory and give it permissions `755`.

Comment: You can also check this: **[\[GUIDE\]\[SELinux\] How to Set and Keep SELinux on Permissive](https://forum.xda-developers.com/g2-mini/general/guide-how-to-set-selinux-to-permissive-t3329439)**